# listview onitemclicklistener for a custom layout

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a `listview`:

```
   <ListView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
```

the elements that go inside it are like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.76"
        android:text="Choose"
        android:clickable="true" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_share"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="share"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_spent"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.11"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="spent"
        android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want that when I click on the `TextView`, something should happen. I have set the `setOnItemClickListener` via the `getListView()` but it does not work.

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"clicked id="+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and

```
        ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

What do I do to make the textview clicable?

***EDIT***: my adapter code:

```
    private class PeopleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public Cursor cursor;
    public ArrayList<PersonInfo> peopleList;
    public ArrayList<PersonInfo> unsavedPeopleList;

    public PeopleListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cursor = cursor;
        peopleList = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>(cursor.getCount());
    }

    public PeopleListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,
            ArrayList<PersonInfo> unsavedList) {
        this(context, cursor);
        this.unsavedPeopleList = unsavedList;
    }

    /**
     * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of
     * speeches in our array.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return peopleList.size() + unsavedPeopleList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
     * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
     * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
     * list.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }


    /**
     * Use the array index as a unique id.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Make a view to hold each row.
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
     *      android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid
        // unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is
        // no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView
        // supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_person_info,
                    null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
            // views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
            holder.share = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.edittext_share);
            holder.spent = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.edittext_spent);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        PersonInfo p = getPersonInfo(position);
        holder.name.setText(p.name);
        holder.name.setTag(p.lookupUri);
        holder.share.setText(p.share + "");
        holder.spent.setText(p.spent + "");

        return convertView;
    }

    PersonInfo getPersonInfo(int position) {
        if (position < peopleList.size()) {
            PersonInfo pInfo = peopleList.get(position);
            if (pInfo == null) {
                pInfo = new PersonInfo();
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                pInfo.lookupUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(0));
                Cursor c = NewEventActivity.this.getContentResolver()
                        .query(pInfo.lookupUri,
                                new String[] { Contacts._ID,
                                        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }, null,
                                null, null);
                pInfo.share = cursor.getInt(1);
                pInfo.spent = cursor.getInt(2);
                try {
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        pInfo.name = c.getString(1);
                    }
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                peopleList.set(position, pInfo);

            }

            return pInfo;
        } else {
            return unsavedPeopleList.get(position - peopleList.size());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide you Adapter code.......

Comment: Have you tried `onListItemClick`

Comment: Still your problem didn't solve yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Click listener Listener to TextView in Adapter in getView() function  ......

see this [link](http://www.rochdev.com/2011/05/clickable-textview-in-listview.html)

```
        private class PeopleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
OnClickListener {

     ..............................
      ............................


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       
             ......................
           .....................
        holder.name.setText(p.name);
        //holder.name.setTag(p.lookupUri);
        holder.share.setText(p.share + "");
        holder.spent.setText(p.spent + "");

        holder.name.setOnClickListener(this);
       holder.name.setTag(position);



        return convertView;
    }

     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Sample", "Clicked on tag: " + v.getTag());
        ////get PersonInfo using getPersonInfo(position) 
    }
```

Comment: He's using `listactivity` so, how would the `getView()` function there ?

Comment: @prongs Please provide you Adapter code.....so that I will provide as per your need.....

Comment: for general Idea see this link http://www.rochdev.com/2011/05/clickable-textview-in-listview.html

Comment: @SpK if I am not wrong that would be in Adapter....? so it depends on adapter and he is using custom layout so should have custom adapter ..?

Comment: that is just a hack right? I need to know the index of the element clicked.

Comment: @prongs as per one other solution I have query.. if am not wrong you are looking for spread click than List item ? right? means two click on each row one for list item and 2nd for textview?

Comment: In general we set the position in tag on Textview but you are already using setTag of Textview ............

Comment: yes, I need the lookupUri, If I can store that in some other way, I can use the position as tag

Comment: I think easy solution will be you can create a class having two attribute url and portion and set this call object as tag.......

Comment: or better one only set the position in tag and get PersonInfo  using  getPersonInfo(position)

Comment: yes great!. But still my problems don't end. on click I need to launch another activity and compute new text of this textview based on its result. The only way I can think of is to set a global variable in onclick but that would be wrong since the user may click multiple textviews in a small time interval. can you suggest any `elegant` solution?

Comment: another activity and compute new text of this textview based on its result ?? sorry not get

Comment: I am showing a contact's name in the text view. On click, I want contact picker to launch and return me what the user chooses.

Comment: so in new activity you contact name may change and you need to update that Text back in list?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12837/discussion-between-prongs-and-dheeresh-singh)

Comment: @DheereshSingh now I want to click on the Textview (or any other childview) in the listview and the onItemClick method work, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ListActicvity then there is a default method available called, `onListItemClick()`. You have to override this method in your ListActivity,

```
protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, android.view.View v, int position, long id) {

        //find which item is clicked using the view object
    };
```

Comment: ` @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Toast.makeText(this, "hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
 }
`

Comment: Did u try without calling super.onListItemClick?

Comment: yes. still doesn't work. :(. anyways it should not make any difference since `super` call happens after the `toast.show()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Set on ClickListener In your getListView() method TextView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood,this is what you want : You want the TextView inside the ListView to be clickable perform some operation based on that,and you have the items with a custom layout inside the ListView

So : setOnItemClickListener **will not work** because it adds a listener for an entire item inside the ListVIew and not on the elements inside that.

To achieve that you can do this :
add a tag to the elements inside your ListView and inside the getView method you are being provided with the position by default, using that and using the tag by using getTag() method you can distinguish what was clicked and in the xml you can simpy declare onClick() and provide with its definition